# Send a code for password reset via email - Swift + Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am creating a simple Swift app. I have got the login working with Swift app. Now, when a user clicks on forgot-password, I want to send them an email with a code. Once he enters that code, he can enter a new password.

I looked up at Firebase.auth.auth() I saw functions like checkActionCode() and applyActionCode() - I couldnot understand a clear difference between them!

I also saw some other functions like confirmpasswordReset() and verifyPasswordResetCode().

However, I do not understand what function to use and how to send an email with the code. Can someone give me an overview of how can I do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user forgot their password, you can [send them a password reset email](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#send_a_password_reset_email) with:

> ```
> Auth.auth().sendPasswordReset(withEmail: email) { (error) in
>   // ...
> }
> ```

This email contains so-called OOB code and a link to an auto-generated page that allows them to reset their password. I recommend getting started with this approach, since you'll have to do the least work to get it up and running.

If you want to create your own page instead of the auto-generated one, have a look at the [documentation on custom email action handlers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler). That page also contains an example showing how to call the `handleResetPassword`, `handleRecoverEmail`, and `handleVerifyEmail` methods.

Comment: Is there any check to know before sending reset password email that user is even existed? What if user is not even signed up?

Comment: This method sends a password reset email to the current signed in user, so the user must have signed up and in to be able to use this code. If you have a different question, I recommend posting it as a new question so that you can provide the full context for what you're asking, and that more people will see it.